# MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean in Spring Batch uses Jdbc-based Daos, not the Map-based

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am implementing a small REST-service, which runs batch job. I am not going to persist any metadata and my job is not parallel, so I've choosed MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean. And I also have H2 in classpath for other purposes. But when I trying to run the job, I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

I figured out, that JobRepository bean I getting from MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean uses *JdbcJobExecutionDao* instead of *MapJobExecutionDao*. And because of that it fails on request

```
SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?
```

Why this happens? How should I properly configure it to use Map-based Dao?

Currently my configuration is the following:

```
public class ServiceConfiguration {

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
    return  mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "inMemoryJobRepository")
public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    JobRepository mapJobRepository = mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    return mapJobRepository;
}

@Bean(name = "syncJobLauncher")
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(@Qualifier("inMemoryJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

    return simpleJobLauncher;
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As Michael Minella mentioned, the bean for custom BatchConfigurer should be created.

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("inMemoryJobRepository") JobRepository jobRepository,
                                        @Qualifier("syncJobLauncher") JobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                        @Qualifier("resourcelessTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                        @Qualifier("inMemoryJobExplorer") JobExplorer jobExplorer){

    return new InMemoryBatchConfigurer(jobRepository, transactionManager, jobLauncher, jobExplorer);
}
```

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot based app?  If so, if there is a `DataSource` on the classpath, Boot will use it.

Comment: Yes, I use Spring Boot, so is there any way to use in-memory JobRepository with it?

Comment: There is, but you need to create your own `BatchConfigurer` and override the `getJobRepository()` method to return the `Map` based one.

Comment: Thanks, that works!